# Split available width between two divs

Tags: css, css-float

I have a container (width is not known) containing four divs, as follows:

```
| Div1 | Div2 ............... | .............. Div3 | Div4 |
```

The leftmost and rightmost divs (Div1/Div4) are fixed width; that's the easy part.

The width of Div2/Div3 is not known, and I would like to avoid setting a fixed width for them, as depending on the content one can be much wider than the other (so I cannot just e.g. have each one use 50% of the available space)

I would like the width of Div2/Div3 to be automatically computed by the browser, then if there is any remaining space left, they should stretch to fill any remaining space (it does not matter how the remaining space is split between Div2/Div3)

The way I am approaching this right now is:

- Div1 floated left (or absolutely positioned)
- Div4 floated right (or absolutely positioned)
- Div2 has a margin-left equal to the width of Div1 (known)
- Div3 has a margin-right equal to the width of Div4 (known)

My question is, how to have Div2 and Div3 stretch to fill the remaining available width? I guess one option would be to use display: table, and another possibility would be [flex-box](http://caniuse.com/flexbox). Are there any alternatives?

**Update:** Edited for clarity.

**Update 2:** Please note that *I cannot assume that Div2 and Div3 should each get 50% of the available space*. This is explicitly stated in the question but somehow I keep getting answers based on this assumption.

Comment: Obviously tables are the easiest and most compatible solution here (I don't understand why people are so afraid to use tables).

Comment: Tables are indeed a solution. I am just wondering if there are alternatives.

Comment: `display:table` / `table-row` / `table-cell` for the rescue?

Comment: definitely could go for flexbox with a fallback or CSS table.

Comment: CSS3 - yes. But please note that I am specifically looking for alternatives to flexbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make use of `overflow:hidden` (or overflow:auto - as long as overflow isn't set to visible [the default]) to trigger `block formatting contexts` to fill remaining width

(I have assumed a fixed width of 100px for div1 and div4)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/7RfG3/1/)**

### Markup

```
<div class="div1">DIV 1</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="div2">DIV 2</div>
    <div class="div3">DIV 3</div>
</div>
<div class="div4">DIV 4</div>
```

### CSS

```
html,body,div
{
    height: 100%;
}
.div1 {
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    background: aqua;
}
.container
{
   overflow: hidden;
   padding-right: 100px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
    background: green;
}
.div2 {
    background:yellow;
    float:left;
}
.div3 {
    background:brown;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.div4 {
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    background:pink;
    width: 100px; 
}
```

Comment: This looks very good! My only problem with this is that if Div2 is very wide, Div3 completely goes away (http://jsfiddle.net/2AURQ/)...

Comment: While we are at this, why is overflow:hidden needed? Seems to work all the same with overflow:auto...

Comment: @Grodriguez - I updated your fiddle with max-width:80% and min-width:20% on div2. div3 fills up the remaining horizontal width. [max-width demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/2AURQ/2/) & [min-width demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/2AURQ/4/) . Note: Your original question doesn't specify what should be done if div2 contains loads of content or no content at all ... my min/max widths are estimations :)

Comment: Also, I edited my answer to include the fact that overflow:auto also triggers a block formatting context

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it is the only one which gives an alternative solution besides the two options that I already mentioned in the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

I came up with 3 different solutions to get the proper width:

- Table cells:

  ```
  parent: {display: table}

  childs: {display: table-cell}
  ```
- Flex grid:

  ```
  parent: {display: inline-flex}

  childs: {flex-grow: 1}
  ```
- Box-sizing container:

  ```
  parent: {float: left}

  container: {box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0 WIDTH}

  childs: {width: 50%}
  ```

The last solution uses extra html markup and aligns elements vertically using relative positioning (means you must have fixed heights).

I suggest you use the first solution, since it's more compatible with older browsers, it's simple to implement and works just fine.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R8mqR/9/embedded/result/

Comment: Thank you. Note that solution 3 does not work as it incorrectly assumes that the available space can be split 50/50 between div2 and div3, which will not work if one has much more content than the other.

Comment: True fact. I just added the last solution to show that the "auto width" can be achieved by the box-sizing approach, but there are sure lots of problems with it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow. In solutions 1 and 2, the width of div2 and div3 adapts to the content, as desired. In "solution" 3, the width of div2 and div3 is hardcoded to 50%. How is this "auto width"?

Comment: As you can see in the updated fiddle, the 3 solutions work in a very similar way. But you are totally right about the adaptation, width is not "auto".

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using display:table without actually using table,tr,td, etc:
([FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fred02138/kfJg4/))

HTML

```
<div id="foo">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="center1">asdfasdfasdf</div>
    <div id="center2"> asdfasdlfkjasl;dkfjalsdjkf</div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    border: solid 1px black ;
    height: 20px;
}

#foo {
    border: none; 
    display: table; 
    width: 100%;
}

#left, #right {width: 100px;}

#foo > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Yes, tables were the obvious option. I was interested to see alternatives to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the Div2 and the Div3 inside a parent Div, and set the width of the Div2 and the Div3 to 50%.

```
<div id="div1"> </div>
<div style="margin-left:*div1width*;margin-right:*div4width*;">
  <div id="div2" style="width:50%"> </div>
  <div id="div3" style="width:50%"> </div>
</div>
<div id="div4"> </div>
```

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem - you just reduced the number of divs from 2 to 1.

Comment: As stated in the question I would like to avoid setting the width of div2/div3.

Comment: @tborychowski You're right, but div tags are used for organizational or stylistic applications. And I don't know a way to mix percentages and absolute values for length unless for a fixed width design.

Comment: @Grodriguez I didn't set their value in px or in a absolute way. I used percentages 50%.

Comment: I did not say that I didn't want to use pixels, I said that I did not want to set the width. I want the width for div2/div3 to be computed automatically, then stretched to fill any remaining space (in fact pretty much the same as a table layout would do)

Comment: @Grodriguez why not specifying a percentage for the div2 and div3 size? At least you know what you put in them. And all div tags need to know their width or else they become full width.

Comment: 1. Because I don't know in advance what will be the content of div2/div3 and how should the space be split. 2. No, div tags don't need to know their width in advance. There are at least two solutions to my problem (using tables or display:table, and flex-box layout). I am asking if there are alternatives.

Comment: @Grodriguez (I meant with display block not other options such as  display table) So I think the best answer is tabular design or css display table property, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The calc (http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) way:

```
#foo {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#foo:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}

#foo > div {
    width: calc(50% - 100px);
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#foo > div:nth-child(1) {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #f00;
}

#foo > div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #0f0;
}

#foo > div:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #00f;
}

#foo > div:nth-child(4) {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/YPWcW/

The padding/position way:

```
#foo {
    padding: 0 100px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#foo:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}

#foo > div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#foo > div:nth-child(1) {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #f00;
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#foo > div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #0f0;
}

#foo > div:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #00f;
}

#foo > div:nth-child(4) {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/qqR4Z/

You can use min-width:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/38KQt/2/

Comment: You were a little bit earlier.

Comment: How does this exactly help? You are still splitting the available width (100% - 200px) equally between Div2/Div3, which I explicitly said I cannot do. See: http://jsfiddle.net/38KQt/1/

Comment: @Grodriguez, try the other example then.

Comment: The other example doesn't make any difference. You are still assuming that the space can be split 50/50 between Div2 and Div3, which is not the case. And it is not a matter of setting a minimum width.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did't read that, take a look at @fred02138 solution using table display, tables do just what you want.

Answer (score 1):

i think it is possible using flex box model in css3

The following code works in IE10,chrome,firefox,safari

```
<div class="mainbox">
<div class="marpad marpadout">
       div1
    </div>
    <div class="subbox marpad">
       div2
    </div>
    <div class="subbox marpad">
       div3
    </div>
    <div class="marpad marpadout">
       div4
    </div>
</div>
```

The styles are:

```
.mainbox{
    width:100%;
    display:-moz-box;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:box;
    background:#ff0000;
 }

.subbox{
    -moz-box-flex:1;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    -ms-flex:1; 
    box-flex:1;
}

.marpad{
margin:5px;
padding: 0 10px 10px 0;
background:#ccc;
}
.marpadout{
width:100px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, flexbox is one of the possibilities indeed.

Answer (score 0):

My solution borrows on others that were already posted, but by testing them, I found that *the content within the two central divs messed up with the distribution of width*... They would retain the same width as long as they had exactly the same content, but would be unevenly wide as soon as one got more content.

So in my solution I used jQuery to distribute the remnant width to the two central divs, **making their width even regardless of differences on their content**.

`Bonus #1:` jQuery doesn't need to know the width of the left and right divs ***explicitly***, as it fetches whatever width has been defined through CSS.

`Bonus #2:` Easily specify how many center divs are there and share the remaining width equally among all of them. Just change the number the remaining width is divided by.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamyguy/jVXez/). Below is the solution as posted in the fiddle, simplified. ***The fiddle shows, in greater detail, the flaws of other solutions when content comes into the central divs***.

```
<style>
    div { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; } 
    .js-container { border: 1px solid red; display: table; }
    .with-width { width: 80%; }
    .js-child { border: 1px solid gray; display: table-cell; }
    .left,
    .right { width: 100px; }
</style>

<h3>Using javascript to dynamically distribute the remaining width</h3>
<div class="js-container with-width">
    <div class="js-child left">left</div>
    <div class="js-child center">center</div>
    <div class="js-child center">center</div>
    <div class="js-child right">right</div>
</div>
<div class="js-container with-width">
    <div class="js-child left">left</div>
    <div class="js-child center">center left <em>doesn't get wider</em> because of extra content</div>
    <div class="js-child center">center right</div>
    <div class="js-child right">right</div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function containerWidth() {
            var w = parseInt($('.js-container').outerWidth(), 10);
            return w;
        }
        // console.log('containerWidth: ' + containerWidth());
        function outerChildrenWidth() {
            var wl = parseInt($('.js-container').find('.left').outerWidth(), 10);
            var wr = parseInt($('.js-container').find('.right').outerWidth(), 10);
            return wl + wr; // bonus #1
        }
        // console.log('outerChildrenWidth: ' + outerChildrenWidth());
        function centerChildWidth() {
            var w = (containerWidth() - outerChildrenWidth()) / 2; // bonus #2
            return w;
        }
        // console.log('centerChildWidth: ' + centerChildWidth());
        function setCenterChildWidth() {
            $('.js-container').find('.center').css('width', centerChildWidth() + 'px');
        }
        setCenterChildWidth();
    });
</script>
```

Note that the `js-`prefix on some classes is there because I used it to separate the javascript-influenced markup from the "normal" one. I've also kept console logs in case you'd like to debug.

Comment: "Making their width even regardless of differences on their content" is exactly what I *don't* want.

Comment: Well, now I know... :D

Answer (score -1):

> IF you know the width of DIV1 and DIV4 then try to find the width of
>   other two div in %.try to give width in % to DIV2 and DIV3.IT will
>   work.

Comment: Sure. But I said I am looking for a solution that does not require setting the width of div2/div3.